# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirect due to probable configuration error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am getting Internal Server Error from Apache server. I looked into log and found this message:

"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

I have spent last two hours by reading various solutions, but I could not find any help.

Everything worked perfectly, but then I installed wordpress in a subfolder, so it was available on mydomain/wordpress. Later I decided to delete it and web started to give me this error. I am able to get to homepage, but any other page does not work. When I looked closer into Apache log, I found out, that there is a loop to no more existing wordpress site. During whole process I have not changed .htaccess file nor any code from my web. All happened on localhost. Does anyone know, what the issue could be? Thank you

Comment: Well, I had another .htaccess file in C: directory, which was causing this problem...

Comment: You might not have changed .htaccess but when you installed WordPress, did it make any change? Post the content of `.htaccess` to understand it better.